# Angular controllers: logic as methods or add to scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say that I had a previous function that wasn't exposed via my API ,and now I decided to expose the function (in my case for test coverage).

What are the arguments for putting objects I want accessible outside of the controller constructor as a property of $scope vs. a `this.propertyName` on the controller?

Comment: both ways are possible and would work, the accepted(standard) way is the `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

The only logical different is that many things have access to `$scope`, but not everything has access to the context of the controller. A controller is just a standard Javascript constructor function, so anything that might call it as one can access things defined on `this`. But HTML templates cannot: they can only see things defined on `$scope`. So the standard is (roughly):

**Controller:** Use `$scope` for things shared by HTML templates, directives, etc. Use `this` for components accessed locally or in only very limited cases such as by testing harnesses (if at all).

**Directive:** Use `$scope` for anything shared by HTML templates or other directives/controllers. Avoid using `this`.

**Service:** Use `this` for everything you want to expose externally. Define local (private) vars for everything else.

**Filter:** Avoid exposing properties/methods externally. Filters aren't meant to be used that way.